# How to show pivot data without directly using pivot statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to pivoting the data without directly using the pivot function.

I have a simple table `t1` which has:

```
ID              Employee Name
100                Amit
100               Rohan
101               Rohit
102               Pradnya
```

My expected output is:

```
100 101  103
2    1    1
```

I want to achieve this without using pivot. I tried using:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN id = '101' THEN '101'
               END,
               CASE
                 WHEN id = '102' THEN '102'
               END,
               CASE
                 WHEN id = '103' THEN '103'
               END,
               Count(*) cnt
        FROM   t1
        GROUP  BY CASE
                    WHEN id = '101' THEN '101'
                  END,
                  CASE
                    WHEN id = '102' THEN '102'
                  END,
                  CASE
                    WHEN id = '102' THEN '102'
                  END);
```

How can I achieve the output without pivot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sort of there, try the following:

```
with s as (
    select id, Count(*) cnt
    from t
    group by id
)
select
    max(case when id=100 then cnt end) as '100',
    max(case when id=101 then cnt end) as '101',
    max(case when id=102 then cnt end) as '102'
from s
```

See [Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0929dc230b1eece8e0a86ce34da9e09)

Comment: Why max needs to be used? I think we dont need tonuse max?

Comment: @DikshitKarki why don't you edit the Fiddle and see what happens without it, then let me know?